# Error: Internal error ocurred in smartMoveTargets (configparser.cpp:1538)

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

It's the first time I use cqtdeployer to deploy my qt project. I installed cqtdeployer from snap store using

```
sudo snap install cqtdeployer
```

Then I ran

```
/mnt/NewVolume1/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake -config release
```

To build my project on release mode.

To deploy my application using cqtdeploy I ran

```
cqtdeployer -bin ScreenOverLayMeextension -qmake /mnt/NewVolume1/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake -qmlDir ./
```

Then it show me this error

```
NewVolume1/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake -qmlDir ./
Info: Deploy ...
Info: The targetDir option is not used. CQtDeployer will use default target dir :/mnt/NewVolume1/main_file_folder/QtProjects/ScreenOverLayMeextension/DistributionKit
Info: Deploy only C/C++ libraries because all target applications do not depend on the Qt libraries
Error: Internal error ocurred in smartMoveTargets (configparser.cpp:1538).
Error: If you see this message please create a new issue about this problem on the official github page https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/issues/new/choose. 
Error: Fail to copy targets
Error: The CQtDeployer fail to deploy application.
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try deploy your application on the **mnt** folder. The **mnt** folder is closed for snap package by default. So you need to add required permissions to your snap package.

Adding needed permissions:

```
 sudo snap connect cqtdeployer:process-control 
 sudo snap connect cqtdeployer:removable-media
 sudo snap connect cqtdeployer:system-backup
```